# What is the best formula for make sequence rotation in excel/sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I would like to know what is the best formula for make sequence rotation in excel/sheet.

For example, I have a dataset like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/639ki.png)

and I want to make the sequence rotation like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qiBl.png)

Thanks!

Comment: There is not yet enough information to answer your question. Are you literally trying to create the sequence of the numbers 1-15 in this rotation? Or will you be trying to rotate a sequence of strings (e.g., names, etc.) or other data that is not of itself sequential? The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to a sample spreadsheet that is set up as close to your real sheet with regard to layout and data types. If you choose to share such a link, be sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Hi Erik,
Thank you for your input, I will make the question more clear in the future. Actually this is my first question in this forum. Will do better 

Comment: Suhuyong, this can be done with a single formula instead of many. But I will need to know the answers to my questions above before I could offer such a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an if statement?

=IF(A1=1,15,A1-1)

If your data starts in a1, type that formula in b1, then drag the bottom corner of the formula to the right as far as you want. Then with all of the cells in row 1 highlighted, drag the bottom right hand corner of farthest right cell highlighted down.